# How does CoreData prevent the instantiation of abstract entities?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, entity, abstract-class

I was able to instantiate and persist instances of abstract entity in coredata, which I did not expect because abstract entities are suppose to not be able to be instantiated. Are abstract entities actually treated differently by core data at all? Or does the `Abstract Entity` checkbox in the xcode coredata model editor's inspector panel merely serve a notional value?